# How do I change the tab completion's behavior of oh-my-fish?

Tags: shell, unix, fish, oh-my-zsh, oh-my-fish

## oh-my-zsh and bash's tab completion

In the tab completion of oh-my-zsh and bash, we have typed a command (for example,`cut`) and we want to a long option (for example,`--delimiter`) which should have a option's arguments behind it .

If we want using tab completion to help us to input the long option, oh-my-zsh or bash will input the long option with equal sign (for example,`--delimiter=`).

## example

input following chars:

```
cut --d
```

if we using oh-my-zsh, and press **TAB** key,we'll get :

```
cut --delimiter=
```

if we using oh-my-fish, and press **TAB** key,we'll get:

```
cut --delimiter
```

the *equal sign(`=`)* is changed into *space sign()*.

## Question

How do I change the tab completion's behavior of oh-my-fish to letting oh-my-fish's tab completion have *equal sign(`=`)* after a long option which should be followed by arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the responsibility of OMF. Completions are handled by fish. I thought there was an open issue discussing changing the current behavior to include the equal-sign but I can't find it. So feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/new. However since almost all commands use the standard getopt_long() function (or something similar) which allows using either a space or equal-sign to separate the value from the flag you'll need to explain why this change is necessary.